# Key binding for letters with diacritics?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to create a new key binding that puts out a single letter with a key combination. For example: `M-E` inserts an "ê" character. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look on this excellent reference on "mastering emacs":
https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs

Comment: Yes, bind a key to a command that uses `insert-char` to insert that character.

Comment: FYI, at least as tested on emacs 25 pretest version, `C-x 8 ^ e` inserts `ê`. Similarly using `A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, `U`, `a`, `i`, `o`, `u` after `C-x 8 ^` would work as you would guess.

Comment: I try to insert this command inside my .emacs file: '**(global-set-key (kbd "M-x e") "ê")**' but there is an error...

Comment: @sblindo `M-x` is already bound to a command so it can't be a prefix for a keybinding (as the error msg says).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e") '(lambda () (interactive) (insert-char 234)))
```

How to get 234? Place your cursor on the letter `ê` and press `C-x =`. Modeline will show you the codes:

```
Char: ê (234, #o352, #xea, file ...) point=3 of 27 (7%) column=0
```

Comment: Why not simply `(insert "ê")`, without having to look the char up?