# Key bound to string does not handle some chars in string correctly

Tags: key-bindings, character-encoding, keyboard-macros, insert

(I ask this question after reading [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/23933/184).)

---

The form

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e") "e")
```

is, as far as I can tell, equivalent to

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "e")))
```

However, after evaluating

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e") "abcdeéfghij")
```

pressing `M-e` inserts

```
abcde   fghij
```

(3 spaces instead of `é`). Looking up the keybinding, it appears that `M-e` is not really bound to `(insert ...)`, but rather to a keyboard macro inserting all these chars... except that the `é` became a `M-i`. With a `ê` it's a linefeed (`M-j`). With a `à` it enters some menu (`M-backtick`), and so on.

But there isn't any problem if I create a macro using the keys for these characters.

---

So, the question is simple: what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is going on is that string in Emacs have historically been used in this context for 2 different purposes:

- sequence of *characters*.
- sequence of *events*.

In your case, you're writing what you think as a sequence of characters, but it's used in a context where Emacs expects a sequence of events.

Since Emacs-19 added support for GUIs, events have become a lot more complex, so sequences of events can also be represented as *vectors* rather than as *strings*.  And this is usually the better option since it avoids this whole issue.  IOW I'd recommend you write:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e") [?a ?b ?c ?d ?e ?é ?f ?g ?h ?i ?j])
```

or

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e") (kbd "abcdeéfghij"))
```

or even

```
(global-set-key [?\M-e] [?a ?b ?c ?d ?e ?é ?f ?g ?h ?i ?j])
```

Since `kbd` is a function that turns a "human readable" string representation of events into an actual vector of events.

You could also `M-x report-emacs-bug` arguing that Emacs should figure out that the `é` (character code 233 (which is 128 + 105 where 105 is the code of `i` and 128 is the 7th bit that's used as the *meta* modifier in some contexts)) is really just a character and not the `\M-i` event, but it's probably difficult to fix this case without breaking existing code, since a lot of code still (mis)uses strings to represent sequences of events as if GUIs didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Out of curiosity, I went to check the release date for emacs 19... apparently that's 1994 (first beta in 1992). It's not that often that I meet a bug that's almost as old as I am! `:)` One question though: it seems from what you say that `kbd` does basically the same job as this legacy code (converting a string to a sequence of events), but much better from a 2016 point of view. Wouldn't this behavior be "easily" fixed by replacing this legacy code with calls to `kbd` where applicable (e.g. when binding keys)?

Comment: Also, I think you mean that 128 is the 8th* bit.

Comment: Right, I guess 8th is a better way to describe it (I was thinking "bit 7" when counting from 0, but I wouldn't call bit 0 "the 0th bit", I'd call it "the first bit").

Comment: @T.Verron: The existing string representation of a sequence of events can't be changed without breaking existing code, so we can't just call `kbd` for the user, because we can't know if the string uses the old format or the "kdb format".  My favorite option would be to signal an error when using a string as a "sequence of events" (or at least emit a warning) so as to force authors to update their code and use a vector (which they can do via `kbd` if they want).

Answer (score 5):

global-set-key is just a thin wrapper around define-key, ignoring some error checking it is

```
(defun global-set-key (key def)
   (define-key (current-global-map) key def))
```

The documentation for define-key says that the "def" can be a number of things, including

```
a string (treated as a keyboard macro),
```

So then there is the question about what something like ê is stored as. This typically has a character code of 0xea or 0x80+0x6a. 0x6a is the character code for j. The meta modifier is typically encoded as setting the top bit (0x80), hence ê being the same as M-j, and as a keyboard macro running something like comment-indent-newline.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Remains the question of why `é` (single key on my keyboard) gets transformed to `M-i` in these "def" strings, but behaves correctly if I define the keyboard macro myself. It's the translation from string to kbd macro which doesn't handle extended ascii correctly?